# UIAlertController with UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet is too small on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I want to change over from the deprecated UIActionSheet to a UIAlertController with UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet.

My updated code works fine on an iPhone and looks pretty much like the old UIActionSheet version, but on an iPad the resulting popover is just two lines high: one for the title and one for all of the options. Is there some way of making it show all of the options at the same time?

Below is the non-working UIAlertController version.

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:[Loc text: @"_title_view_menu"] message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:[Loc text: @"_action_dataset_items"]
          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
          handler: ^(UIAlertAction *action) {
              [self buttonPressed: mainMenuDatasetItems];
          }]];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:[Loc text: @"_action_my_items"]
          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
          handler: ^(UIAlertAction *action) {
              [self buttonPressed: mainMenuMyItems];
          }]];        
[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:[Loc text: @"_action_cancel"]
          style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
          handler: ^(UIAlertAction *action) {

            }]];


actionSheet.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = viewController.view;
actionSheet.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = viewController.view.frame;
[viewController presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: FYI - You should never set the sourceView/sourceRect to the view controller's entire view. It should be a much smaller portion of the view such as a specific button or other subview.

Comment: @rmaddy, i'm invoking this routine from a UIBarButtonItem which isn't a view, so I can't use it to set sourceView. However... I can set actionSheet.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem to this, and that fixes the problem... thanks!

Comment: @rmaddy: as I already said: I did, I could, and it worked.

Comment: if u set actionSheet.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem make sure popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections is set correct or is not set at all. Otherwise you can get small alert popup